# Starting background task in UWP via DependencyService

Tags: c#, xamarin, win-universal-app

I have been trying to run code in the background. So far I managed to register the task, but the Run method is never executed. This is what I have so far:

BackgroundUWP:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(App.UWP.BackgroundUWP))]
namespace App.UWP
{
    class BackgroundUWP : IBackground
    {
        public async void RegisterAndStartTask()
        {
            string taskName = typeof(MyTask).Name;

            foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            {
                if (task.Value.Name == taskName)
                {
                    task.Value.Unregister(true);
                    break;
                }
            }

            BackgroundTaskBuilder builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
            ApplicationTrigger trigger = new ApplicationTrigger();
            builder.Name = taskName;
            builder.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(MyTask).FullName;
            builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
            BackgroundTaskRegistration t = builder.Register();

            await trigger.RequestAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

MyTask:

```
namespace App.UWP
{
    public sealed class MyTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            // this method isn't being called
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="App.UWP.MyTask">
  <BackgroundTasks>
    <Task Type="systemEvent" />
  </BackgroundTasks>
</Extension>
```

My app reaches `await trigger.RequestAsync();` when I set a breakpoint. In the console I notice this message `backgroundTaskHost.exe has exited with code 1`. What can I do to fix this?

EDIT:

Might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353382/universal-windows-app-background-task-has-exited-with-code-1-0x1) question. My project looks like this:

- App (PCL)
- App.UWP

Comment: As i know you don't need to add this Run method. An async method already create a task. If you put the keyword await you just wait for the return. if you don't want to wait for the return, remove await

Comment: I followed [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task) tutorial and it says I need to implement IBackgroundTask which forces you to implement the Run method.

Comment: Mistake from my side, i do not understand the backgroundTask and this change since 8.1, I did not do like that. Sorry i can't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a new Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows) project with a class implementing IBackgroundTask and add a reference to the UWP project.

The problem was that I had the class in the App.UWP project which is not a Windows Runtime Component project.